# numbers[x] is giving incorrect output and i can not figure out why

Tags: java

```
myList.removeAll(Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(0)));
numbers = myList.toArray(new Integer[myList.size()]);  
Collections.sort(myList);
Collections.reverse(myList);
System.out.println(myList);
for(it x = 0; x < myList.size(); x++){
System.out.println(numbers[x]);
System.out.println(x);
```

Lets say the variables were 24, 22, 15, 10. The output is this
    22
    0
    24
    1
    10
    2

And other times it goes in the correct order. Why is that? If you need to see more code feel free to ask and apologies, this is my first time posting on this website and I'm also doing it on my phone because my home internet is out atm

Comment: What is `myList`? What variables are 24, 22, 15, 10? What is correct order? Why are you printing `numbers[x]` and then `x` in the same loop?

Comment: myList is an array of potentially 30 variables. 24 22 15 and 10 are 4 out of the potential 30 in the array. Correct order is it actually taking the correct number from the correct index so 21 0 22 1 15 2 and 10 3. I am printing both in the same loop because i was using it as a diagnostic tool. To make sure that x itself wasnt the issue

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. Doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely both that users will up-vote your posts and that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't really matter which style your choose (although, for some languages, some styles are more appropriate than others). But, *pick one* and *use it consistently* for all code in a single project.

Comment: As I said in my main post this is my first time ever posting on this site. And I had to do it on my phone. So i apologize for the bad formatting but it was due to using a site i don't know very well, on a device i habe trouble formatting on in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are assigning your numbers array before you are sorting and reversing it. A fix should be something like the following...

```
        int[] numbers =  {24, 15, 22, 10};
        List<Integer> listNumbers = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            listNumbers.add(numbers[i]);
        }
        Collections.sort(listNumbers);
        Collections.reverse(listNumbers);
        Integer[] newNumbersArray = listNumbers.toArray(new Integer[listNumbers.size()]);
        for (int i = 0; i < newNumbersArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(newNumbersArray[i]);
        }
```